# Greatest Integer Function: y=c*[x] vs. y=[c*x]

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a difference between `y=c*[x]` versus `y=[c*x]`?

Comment: Sure. Take $x=1/2$, $c=2$.

Comment: So what should I look for in a graph to determine which one it is?

Comment: Depends on $c$. But if for example $c\gt 1$, then $c\lfloor x\rfloor$ will be $0$ between $x=0$ and $x=1$, while $\lfloor cx\rfloor$ will jump to $1$ for some $x$ with $0\lt x\lt 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$2\times \lfloor0.5\rfloor=2\times0=0\ne\lfloor2\times0.5\rfloor=\lfloor1\rfloor=1$$